# How to assign echo value into variable in shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins

Here is my simple code, but its not working as expected.. I wanted to print current date in my Jenkins Pipeline using `sh` and I tried this.. but no luck yet. could someone help me to do this?

```
sh """
currentDate = 'echo "$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"'
echo $currentDate
"""
```

And I am getting error that `currentDate : command not found`

Comment: As you got already an answer, how to do it correctly, here an explanation what happened in your code: A line of the form `X Y Z`  is interpreted as invoking a command X with the parameters Y and Z. In your case, hence, it is interpreted as invoking the command `currentDate` with a lone equal sign as first parameter and a somewhat longer string as the second. The date itself is never calculated in your code; you inhibited this by using single quotes.

Comment: `date` already prints a date. There’s no need for a variable nor for `echo`.

Comment: Yes, this is explained well in the accepted answer. I just want to explain to the OP what happened - or did not happen - in his code.

Comment: actually, I need to pass this ```currentDate``` variable in my next steps of code. so i stored the value in the variable @user1934428 @Biffen

Comment: We all now what you **wanted** to do. I just added an explanation, what you actually **did** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have to use *echo* when you already turned the std output of *date* into a string. You could write directly:

```
currentDate=$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')
echo $currentDate
```

(note: there is no space around the equal sign in the variable assignement).

Second, if you want to turn the output of a command into string, it's not the normal quote ' but the reverse quote ` that you should be using.

So, if you insist on using *echo* , you should write:

```
currentDate=`echo "$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"`
```

Comment: Unless he plans on doing something *evil* with `eval $currentDate` (note: the only difference between the adjective and the command is `'i'` and `'a'` -- they are quite similar otherwise -- avoid the use of `eval`...)

Comment: See also [backtick vs "$()"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/121163)